# Как 'прикрутить' QFileDialog, чтобы выбранные файлы отправить на импортируемый модуль-обработчик?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qfiledialog

У меня есть модуль **treatment.py**, которому на вход нужно подавать **2** файла: **defects.csv** и **data.csv**.

Вместо прямого прописывания пути решил использовать диалоговое окно `QFileDialog` из *PyQt5*.

Когда выбрал оба файла, выпадает след.ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "D:/...", line 63, in  tr.treat(defects, data)
> File "D:\Working\ML\Трещины CD\treatment.py", line 16, in treat
> def90_18 = pd.read_csv(p_def90_18, sep=';', encoding='latin-1')
> File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
> return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
> File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 413, in _read
> filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression)
> File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 232, in get_filepath_or_buffer
> raise ValueError(msg.format(_type=type(filepath_or_buffer)))
> ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class '**main**.App1'>

Использую следующий код диалогового окна:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileDialog
import treatment as tr    

class App1(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.left = 500
        self.top = 300
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.openFileNameDialog1()
        self.show()
        self.close()

    def openFileNameDialog1(self):
        global defects
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        defects, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Выберите файл с \"defects\" ", "", '(*.csv)', options=options)
        if defects:
            return defects


class App2(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.left = 500
        self.top = 300
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.openFileNameDialog2()
        self.show()
        self.close()

    def openFileNameDialog2(self):
        global data
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        data, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Выберите файл \"data\" ", "", '(*.csv)', options=options)
        if data:
            return data


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    defects = App1()
    data = App2()
    tr.treat(defects, data)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А если так: `defects = App1().openFileNameDialog2()` и непонятно зачем вы делаете такой вызов внутри метода  `global defects`?

Comment: global defects я делал, чтобы defects и data были доступны для фунции tr.treat(defects, data). Если делать 'defects = App1().openFileNameDialog2()', то вызывается два окна. Но, не совсем понял... т.к. все присваивается одной переменной 'defects', а нужно 2 : defects  и data.

Comment: не надо глобал вы же возвращаете значение. Эм, короче тут надо все переделать... Сейчас доберусь до купитона

Comment: А у вас всегда имена файлов defects.csv и data.csv? А классы App1 и App2 обязательно должны быть, или достаточно диалоговых окон для выбора файлов?

Comment: defects и data мне нужны, чтобы подать на вход tr.treat(). Я попытался переделать, но почему-то окно вызывается 6 раз(по 3 для openFileNameDialog1 и также 3 для openFileNameDialog2.

Comment: Потому что вы создаете 6 окон. Мы с  @S. Nick предложили вам варианты, выбирайте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Или даже четвертый ):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileDialog
import treatment as tr

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(None, "Выберите файлы данных (data.csv) и дефектов (defects.csv)...", "", "csv (*.csv)", options=options)

    defects = None
    data = None
    for(_file in files)
        if( 'defects' in _file ):
            defects = _file
        else if( 'data' in _file ):
            data = _file

    if defects and data:
        tr.treat(defects, data)
    else:
        print("Что-то пошло не так [" + defects + "," + data +"]")
```

Comment: Под третьим вариантом я имел ввиду использование функции `getOpenFileNames`. Это удобная статическая функция, которая возвращает один или несколько существующих файлов, выбранных пользователем. А четвертый вариант ?

Comment: @S.Nick он перед вами

Comment: У меня 4-ый работает отлично)  S. Nick и Alexander Chernin, Большое Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @СергейЕршов отлично. С превеликим удовольствием приму в дар зеленую галочку ))

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте пример, по-моему вам нужен третий вариант

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileDialog
#import treatment as tr


class App1(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.left = 500
        self.top = 300
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
#        self.openFileNameDialog1()
#        self.show()
#        self.close()

    def openFileNameDialog1(self):
#        global defects
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        defects, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Выберите файл с \"defects\" ", "", '(*.csv)', options=options)
        if defects:
            return defects


class App2(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.left = 500
        self.top = 300
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
#        self.openFileNameDialog2()
#        self.show()
#        self.close()

    def openFileNameDialog2(self):
#        global data
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        data, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Выберите файл \"data\" ", "", '(*.csv)', options=options)
        if data:
            return data

### vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class OpenSheet(QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowModality(True)
        self.setFileMode(self.ExistingFiles)
        self.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog.AcceptOpen)

class App3(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(500, 300, 640, 480)

    def openFileNameDialog3(self):
        diag = OpenSheet()
        options = diag.Options()
        options |= diag.DontUseNativeDialog
        files, _ = diag.getOpenFileNames(None, "Выберите файл \"data\" )", "",
                                        "Csv Files (*.csv)", options=options)
        if files:
            print("Selected files: ", files)             

            return files    
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    d1 = App1()
    defects = d1.openFileNameDialog1()
    print("defects", defects)

    d2 = App2()
    data = d2.openFileNameDialog2()
    print("data", data)

    d3 = App3()
    files = d3.openFileNameDialog3()    
    print("Выбраны фалы: ", files)  

#    tr.treat(defects, data)
#    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавил третий вариант.  Каждый файл просит выбрать 2 раза (или  нажать open). Четвертый вариант это для  2-го питона?

Comment: @СергейЕршов  вы запускали мой пример или модернизированный свой? Если свой то удалите строки `self.openFileNameDialog1()`  и `self.openFileNameDialog2()`

Comment: Свой.  Ок, попробую спасибо.